# how to fix cannot execute query error in postgresql?

Tags: php, postgresql

I installed postgresql in my ubuntu 20.04
I enabled the pg extension in the php.ini file
I tried connecting to my local installation of postgres via console to check if i can connect

e.g

```
psql -h localhost -U root -d test
```

then I got prompted with password... then I input my password

then I got inside and can see `test=#`

then I ran

```
\d
```

and I was able to see the existing tables inside the test database and was
able to do some simple select query..
moving forward....I tried this php snippet in my index.php file

```
$host = "localhost"; 
$user = "root"; 
$pass = "root*"; 
$db = "test"; 

$con = pg_connect("host=$host port=5432 dbname=$db user=$user password=$pass");

$query = "SELECT * FROM person LIMIT 5"; 
$rs = pg_query($con, $query) or die("Cannot execute query: $query\n"); 
$row = pg_fetch_row($rs);

echo $row[0] . "\n";

pg_close($con);
```

when I ran in browser e.g localhost/pg/index.php

I encountered this error

```
Cannot execute query: SELECT * FROM person LIMIT 5
```

any idea why my code can't seem to connect to postgres?

Comment: Check if `pg_connect()` succeeded or returned `FALSE`. Also at this day and age why are you not using Object Oriented Programming...

Comment: var_dump returned false ........this is my first time to use postgresql , am zero knowledge, I have been using mysql and oracle 11g in the past 14 years with php ...am trying to learn it from the beginning

Answer (score 0):

Check if the PG server is listening the port 5432. To do it, run `netstat -na` and search the record 0.0.0.0:5432, as described [here](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/004e01c22c05$18be79b0$05faa8c0@edios)

You could also use PDO instead of pg_connect:

```
$myPDO = new PDO("pgsql:host=$host;dbname=$db", $user, $pass);
```

Comment: even if I corrected that typo you mentioned, it still return false...not sure why...but using console i can connect manually...,php extensions are all enabled..any other idea?

Comment: Have you verified the server is listening the port you are trying to connect with PHP?

Comment: how to this that? can you please modify your answer and include that, if any configuration that I need to modify? which server apache or postgres? ...those basics things i am not aware of

Comment: this is what I saw  ` tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5432          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     176249   /var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432`  so it means it does listens to 5432